# Qutip choi_to_kraus and to_kraus functions are not returning list of Kraus representation

Tags: programming, kraus-representation, qutip

I am trying to find my kraus representation from my process matrix.
Suppose that, I have these process matrix:

```
proces_matrix =  [[ 1.     0.     0.     0.   ]
  [-0.     0.537 -0.004 -0.005]
  [ 0.023  0.014  0.635 -0.03 ]
  [ 0.011 -0.009  0.017  0.883]]]
```

To find the kraus representation, I tried 2 methods.

1. I first tried to use `to_kraus` function in qutip. According to API documentation, to_kraus Converts a Qobj representing a quantum map to a list of quantum objects, each representing an operator in the Kraus decomposition of the given map. When I gave my process matrix to the function, as a result I got my process matrix back.

The code is pretty simple:

```
    q_proces_matrix = qutip.Qobj(proces_matrix)
    kraus_rep = qutip.to_kraus(q_proces_matrix)
```

2. Then I thought, I am doing something wrong so I asked this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/how-to-find-the-kraus-operators-from-the-process-matrix), and thanks to a the answer, I first find my Choi matrix with the function of `to_choi` in qutip and then I used `choi_to_kraus` function in qutip. The definition of the function is [enter link description here](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html) It takes choi matrices and turns kraus representations However I got my process matrices as output instead of Kraus representations.

The code is again pretty simple:

```
q_proces_matrix = qutip.Qobj(proces_matrix)
choi = qutip.to_choi(q_proces_matrix)
kraus_rep = qutip.choi_to_kraus(choi)
```

3. AFter all, I just found the eigenvectors of my Choi matrices and It means the superket operation of my kraus representations. But I am quite confused what I did wrong with qutip function and I did not get my Kraus representations from the functions

Could someone explain me what I missed in qutip?

Comment: it might be easier to answer the question is you add a working code snippet showing what exactly you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QuTiP, there are different Qobj types for operators and superoperators, and the [function](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/modules/qutip/superop_reps.html) `to_choi` will only do what you expect it to if the input has type `super`.  If you change `qutip.Qobj(proces_matrix)` to `qutip.Qobj(proces_matrix, type='super')`, everything should work.

The reason you get the same thing back otherwise is because QuTiP converts to `type=oper` by default with `Qobj()` and thus assumes your input is just an operator in the unvectorized convention, such as a single Kraus operator.  Then with your code you ended up converting this to a Choi matrix and back to just a single Kraus operator.

Comment: As a follow up, this should also work by just using the `to_kraus` function directly - no need to convert to Choi matrix. If the argument given to `to_kraus` has type `super`, it will give you the Kraus operators correctly.

Comment: @chrysaor4 Thanks, you saved me!!